# Why can't I get legendary heroes in RAID: Shadow Legends?

Tags: raid-shadow-legends

I have been playing *RAID: Shadow Legends* for six months and I have never gotten a legendary hero, except Scyl from the daily login mission. That is my only legendary hero. I have not made a purchase for the game but I could have opened more than 100 blue, purple or yellow ores mixed until today.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're paying, Scyl is usually in your first legendaries. In your first months of gameplay you shouldn't really have legendaries.

Here are some guaranteed legendaries:

- Scyl of the Drakes (150 days)
- Visix the Unbowed (270 days)
- Rhazin Scarhide
- Arbiter
- Drexthar Bloodtwin

Your goal at this stage is to get a solid CB team, reach NM clan boss, so you can get summoning shards. That's the most consistent way to get more legendaries.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to guarantee a legendary drop, but there are some "tricks":

- Wait for a boost summon event. Nearly every weekend start a "summon boost" event. They can increase the chance to get a particular hero or increase the chance to get an higher rarity one. Save you shards until you get one of these events, for increased chance to get a leggendary!
- Follow fusion events. Keep an eye for the fusion events. They require you to collect some hero with some events and then use them to create a new legendary! Be aware there is a "permanent" fusion legendary, wich is Razhin.
- Follow the champion shard events. Similar to fusion, these events require you to collect shards of champions via some events. If you hit 100 shards, you get the hero.
- Less early-game friendly, if you complete some parts of the game, you are rewarded with a leggendary. Namely, Arbiteer from Mission, Lydia from Faction Wars, severals from Doom Tower.